# PHP - Wordpress - how to define external URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following internal link defined in my function:

```
$url = site_url( '/internal-page/' );
```

Now I'm trying to define an external URL instead. I thought changing `site_url()` to just `url()` would do the trick.

```
$url = url( 'https://example.com' );
```

But that seems to trigger an error.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: I've just tried `$url = 'https://example.com';` and it works. Is it really as simple as that?

Comment: You just set a variable with a string value man... `$status = 'quo'`, however don't let php functions confuse you... previously when you set `$url = url( 'https://example.com' );`, you were trying to pass 'https://example.com' as a param through `url()` function, which doesn't exist hence why the error was thrown. Please bear in mind these return formats... boolean, strings, integers, arrays and objects.... every return format has its purpose. :)